# HTTP GET from node server takes too long

Tags: node.js

I'm learning node.js currently and I'm stuck with this problem. I was able to successfully create my node.js server and it works when I run it on the terminal. I even console.log the data I am trying to GET and it shows in the terminal but when I try to load it on Postman, it doesn't show anything.

I use localhost:9001/api but it doesn't load. I don't even get any errors.

Here's my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
require('dotenv').config();

const api_key = XXXXXXXXXXX

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.listen(9001, () => console.log('listneing at 9001'));


app.get("/api", async (req,res)=> {
    console.log("getting data")
    const url = `website.com/vi/api/?alt=json&key=${api_key}`
    const options={
        "method" : "GET"
    };
    const response = await fetch(url, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(e =>  {
            console.errror({
                "message": "oh no",
                 error : e,
            });
        });
        console.log(response)


});
```

Not sure how to solve it can anyone please help a new learner?

Answer (score 1):

Postman needs a response from your side to show **Responses**.
The console.log() prints the output on your screen but in order to get response in Postman, You have to return a response like

```
return res.status(response.code).json(response);
```

This is my way of returning response. You can make your own variable and add values to them.

Comment: Where will I put it? Where console.log should be? When I put there  I get an error. `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined`

Comment: let me show you one of my function to show response, It should help you.

exports.noSuchRequestResponse = async(req,res)=> {
    let response = ResponseHelper.setResponse(ResponseCode.NOT_SUCCESS, Message.NO_REQUEST_FOUND);
    return res.status(response.code).json(response);
}

Where ResponseHelper is another helper file I have made to make m,y controller looks simple.

Comment: Sorry I don't still get it, I don't understand a lot at the moment.

Comment: @RudolphMusngi . That's totally okay. 
Just try to change your  const response = await fetch(url, options)    " INTO "     return await fetch(url, options)

Comment: Thanks for being so understanding. It's still really confusing but I tried it and my server started. When I load it on POSTMAN though, it gives another error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236224/discussion-between-rudolph-musngi-and-muhammad-mujtaba-shafique).